# Watch TV on computer through cable input

Tags: tv, cable, camera, video-capture

I have a **DANY USB TV BOX U-1050** (please see attached picture).

[image]

And, I have a normal TV aerial cable (For a lack of a better term, don't know the jargon) See attached picture.

[image]

How do I get this to work together now? The DANY tv box did come with a program that you can load and view tv through that but that was only compatible with Windows 7 and lower. I'm running Windows 8 at the moment... I've heard that one can use something like VLC for this (Which would be great) But I don't have a clue where to start, especially if I want to select multiple channels and so forth.

Any help would greatly be appreciated! Thanks

PS - I obviously know how to connect the DANY to the pc and to the TV cable.

Comment: If the program works on `Windows 7` there is no technical reason it shouldn't work on `Windows 8` unless it actually doesn't work because the installer prevents it.  A programmer has to go to a great deal of effort for something to work on `Windows 7` and NOT work on `Windows 8`.  If the installer were to say attempt to install `.NET Framework 4.0` it would fail, and depending on how they designed their installer, this failure would block the installer from ever working on `Windows 8` since it comes with `.NET Framework 4.5` which is a in-place upgrade to `.NET Framework 4`

Comment: @Ramhound - I know it's really strange. The installer does work and apparently the installation is successful. But as soon as I try and launch the program.. It just doesn't. Running the .exe that launches the program just does.. nothing.

Comment: That would seem to indicate the program is indeed a .NET Program and is expecting certain versions of the reference dlls it uses ( i.e. its poorly programmed ).  Have you tried compatability mode?

Answer (score 1):

Im going to be honest here, I never heard of DANY and decided to look them up.  Long story short, it appears to be cheap and full of problems.  Nothing but issues on other forums talking about bad drivers, a website with links to the wrong products, and no manuals or specifications.  Return it, or throw it away.  You are better off with products from [Hauppauge](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/prods.html) or other respectable TV tuner product.